# Alexgorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter - принудительная подсветка

Tags: javascript

Вот есть такой "подсветчик" кода [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Как с его помощью подсветить код в нужном `<pre>`? Я имею ввиду, что код загружается на страницу с помощью Ajax, поэтому просто в head написать скрипт `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` не работает.

Вот html блок:

```
<div class="protocol-source-code code-highlight">
    <pre class="brush: pas;">
            var
             n,m,q,w,e,sum,i,min,m1,o,t:longint;

            begin
             assign(input,'input.txt');reset(input);
             assign(output,'output.txt');rewrite(output);
             readln(n,m,m1);
             writeln(sum);
            end.
    </pre>
</div>
```

А это скрипт обработки:

```
function afterAjax() {
        var sourceCode = jQuery(".protocol-source-code");
        jQuery(".sourcebutton").click(function () {            
            sourceCode.show();
            applySyntaxHighlight();
        });
}
function applySyntaxHighlight() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['toolbar'] = false;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
}
```

В стилях:

```
 .protocol-source-code
 {
      display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

всего лишь привязывает подсветку кода к событию window.load (прелести opensource - взял и посмотрел как это работает), поэтому нужно вызвать

```
SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()
```

Comment: Прежде всего нужно быть внимательным.

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

после загрузки кода.

Comment: не работает и в консоли эксэпшенов тоже нет